# BehaviorSubject with boolean value is not working as intended

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject, subject-observer

I have implemented a simple `BehaviorSubject`,

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs";

class MyWeirdoClass {

  constructor() {}


  private st: Subject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);


  changeSt(val:boolean){
    this.st.next(val);
  }


  val(){
    this.st.subscribe(res=>{
      if (res){
        console.log(res);
      }
    })
  }

  stStatus() {
    this.val();
    this.changeSt(true);
    this.val();
    this.changeSt(false);
    this.val();
  }


}
```

now when running `stStatus()` gives logs the following output on the console.

```
true
true
```

while I expect the value

```
false
true
false
```

What is wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 5):

The output you're getting is correct:

```
this.val();
```

This just makes the first subscription which doesn't print anything thanks to `if (res) {...}`.

```
this.changeSt(true);
```

Set's the value to `true` which is printed by the first subscription.

```
this.val();
```

Makes the second subscription which prints the second `true`.

```
this.changeSt(false);
```

You set it to `false` which is ignored by all subscribers because of `if (res) {...}`.

```
this.val();
```

The same as above.

Comment: I'm trying to make manual map reload via `reload$`, which for some reason does not work: `this.reload$.pipe(filter(reload => reload === true), tap(reload => reload = false)).subscribe([Map API request])`. Even though the value DOES change to `false`, next time I set `reload$` to `true` externally, it shows that it IS still `true`, so the triggering does not happen. Don't understand why is that. This does not work either: `this.reload$.pipe(filter(reload => reload === true), tap(() => reload$.next(false))).subscribe([Map API request])`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

because these lines:

```
if (res){
  console.log(res);
}
```

the value only gets logged whenever it is truthy.

btw, you misunderstanding the way your code work.